# Safe to delete Windows10Upgrade at 11.0 GB?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I must free up hard drive space. What happens if I delete this folder? [This Reddit thread](https://redd.it/e4o5u4) has no definitive answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Windows10Upgrade** folder is created by **Windows 10 Update Assistant**. If your update is complete, you can safely delete this folder by uninstalling Windows 10 Update Assistant in **Programs and Features**.

Source: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/86213-how-delete-windows10upgrade-folder-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Thanks. How can I double check if my "update is complete"?

Comment: If you installed the update and restarted your PC it is likely complete. You can check under Settings for Windows Update and see if anything is pending there. If you click the power button and it just says "Restart" and not "Update and Restart" then you should be good.